# Impute NA Values in a matrix using linear model

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that will take a matrix of any size, find a single NA value, and impute that value based on a LINEAR MODEL of the other values in the matrix. I'm running into the issue that my linear model is not supplying me with a slope and an intercept to calculate the missing value, as I believe it should. If anyone can give me any pointers or help me find a more efficient way of achieving this, I would appreciate it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
rawVector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 7, 8, 9)
testMatrix <- matrix(rawVector, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = T)


imputeMissingValuesHARD <- function(inputMatrix) {

  dimnames(inputMatrix) <- list(rownames(inputMatrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "row"), colnames(inputMatrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "col"))

  dependent <- ""
  colNumber <- -1

  for(row in 1:nrow(inputMatrix)) {
    for(col in 1:ncol(inputMatrix)) {
        if(is.na(inputMatrix[row, col]))
      {
        dependent <- colnames(inputMatrix)[col]
        colNumber <- col
      }
    }
  }

  otherCols <- colnames(inputMatrix)[-(colNumber)]


  myModel <- as.formula(paste(dependent, paste(otherCols, collapse="+"), sep="~"))


  fit <- lm(myModel, as.data.frame(inputMatrix))

  print(fit)

  return("OK")
}

imputeMissingValuesHARD(testMatrix)
```

Comment: Look up the mice package. I believe it does it for you and you won’t need to write your own program.

Comment: Try to replace `print(fit)` with `print(predict(fit, newdata=as.data.frame(inputMatrix)))`, which would fix your function to yield an "imputed" column 3.